# Extract overlapping substrings from a list of strings using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, list, linq

I have the following list of strings {"a","b","c","d","e"}. How can I obtain sublists of length 3 using LINQ like this:

```
{"a","b","c"}
{"b","c","d"}
{"c","d","e"}
```

I am not looking for every combination

```
 var list = students.OrderBy(student => student.LastName)
                   .Select(student => student);

        List<Student> sortedStudents = list.ToList();

        var triplets = from x in sortedStudents
                       from y in sortedStudents
                       from z in sortedStudents
                       select new { x, y, z};

        StudentListBox.ItemsSource = triplets;
```

I am not looking for something like

```
{"a","b","c"}
{"a","b","d"}
{"a","b","e"}
.............
{"d","a","b"}
{"d","a","c"}
{"d","a","e"} and so on
```

Student class

```
class Student
{
    public Student()
    {

    }

    public String FirstName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public String LastName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public DateTime Birthday
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return FirstName + " " + LastName;
    }
}
```

Comment: any effort from your side other than this post??

Comment: What did you try already? We´re not doing what you´re supposed to do, which is **thinking**.

Comment: I've tried a number of things but those that worked, produced all combinations. Updated the post with some context code and my last attempt

Comment: Could you include the definition of `students` in your code?

Comment: And when you say "I am not looking for every combination", what exactly do you mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can us an overload of `Select` which gets the index of current element as an extra parameter to the selector and use it like this:

```
var triplets = sortedStudents.Take(list.Count - 2)
    .Select((x, i) => new { S1 = x, S2 = list[i+1], S3 = list[i+2] });
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I had problems coming up with a way of grouping based on a starting point and this is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one approach with Linq - `.Take(3)`defines length of 3

```
string[] input = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" };
var result = Enumerable.Range(0, input.Length - 2).Select(x => input.Skip(x).Take(3));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just loop the strings in your array:

```
public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> GetTriples(string[] myArray)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.Length - 2; i++)
    {
        yield return myArray.Skip(i).Take(3);
    }
}
```

This codes loops every string in your array and gets the next two strings.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming (because you haven't got a complete code sample) that you want to take triples of items from your collection in the order in which they appear, you can use a combination of `Skip` and `Take` to give you subsets representing your triples.

```
var triplets = new List<IEnumerable<Student>>();

for(int i = 0; i < (sortedStudents.Count - 2); i++)
{
   triplets.Add(sortedStudents.Skip(i).Take(3));
}
```